# Saving publishing site as template in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, site-template, production

I have a publishing site in moss 2007(dev env) and i need to save it as template.. in moss 2007 there is no option to save the publishing site as template so i am using the link below to save it as a template ..
http://..../_layouts/savetmpl.aspx ....this link lets me to save the template ..is this the right way to do it... will i have any issues when i use this template in the production environment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publishing Site "Save site as template"](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20965/publishing-site-save-site-as-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Save site as template" option for sites with publishing feature is not supported from Microsoft.

Its not supported for 2007 or 2010 officially. But many have tried using it with certain precautions like publishing all the pages and files before saving as template, etc. And it has worked too. But its never guaranteed from Microsoft and the pros or cons are not documented.

Please visit this link for more info- http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2007/09/19/save-site-as-template-option-and-the-publishing-feature.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments